# how to modify resnet 50 with 4 channels as input using pre-trained weights in Pytorch?

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I would like to change the resnet50 so that I can switch to 4 channel input,
use the same weights for the rgb channels and initialize the last channel with a normal with mean 0 and variance 0.01.

here is my code:

```py
import torch.nn as nn
import torch
from torchvision import models

from misc.layer import Conv2d, FC

import torch.nn.functional as F
from misc.utils import *

import pdb

class Res50(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,  pretrained=True):
        super(Res50, self).__init__()

        self.de_pred = nn.Sequential(Conv2d(1024, 128, 1, same_padding=True, NL='relu'),
                                     Conv2d(128, 1, 1, same_padding=True, NL='relu'))
        
        self._initialize_weights()

        res = models.resnet50(pretrained=pretrained)
        pretrained_weights = res.conv1.weight

        res.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(4, 64, kernel_size=7, stride=2, padding=3,bias=False)

        res.conv1.weight[:,:3,:,:] = pretrained_weights
        res.conv1.weight[:,3,:,:].data.normal_(0.0, std=0.01)
        
        self.frontend = nn.Sequential(
            res.conv1, res.bn1, res.relu, res.maxpool, res.layer1, res.layer2
        )
        
        self.own_reslayer_3 = make_res_layer(Bottleneck, 256, 6, stride=1)        
        self.own_reslayer_3.load_state_dict(res.layer3.state_dict())

        
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.frontend(x)
        x = self.own_reslayer_3(x)
        x = self.de_pred(x)
        x = F.upsample(x,scale_factor=8)
        return x

    def _initialize_weights(self):
        for m in self.modules():
            if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
                m.weight.data.normal_(0.0, std=0.01)
                if m.bias is not None:
                    m.bias.data.fill_(0)
            elif isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm2d):
                m.weight.fill_(1)
                m.bias.data.fill_(0)
```

but it produces the following error, does anyone have any advice?

```py
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/tensor.py:746: UserWarning: The .grad attribute of a Tensor that is not a leaf Tensor is being accessed. Its .grad attribute won't be populated during autograd.backward(). If you indeed want the gradient for a non-leaf Tensor, use .retain_grad() on the non-leaf Tensor. If you access the non-leaf Tensor by mistake, make sure you access the leaf Tensor instead. See github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/30531 for more informations.
  warnings.warn("The .grad attribute of a Tensor that is not a leaf Tensor is being accessed. Its .grad "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 62, in <module>
    cc_trainer = Trainer(loading_data,cfg_data,pwd)
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/Folder/Code/trainer.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.net.CCN.parameters(), lr=cfg.LR, weight_decay=1e-4) #remenber was 1e-4
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/optim/adam.py", line 44, in __init__
    super(Adam, self).__init__(params, defaults)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.add_param_group(param_group)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py", line 206, in add_param_group
    raise ValueError("can't optimize a non-leaf Tensor")
ValueError: can't optimize a non-leaf Tensor
```

Answer (score 12):

Ideally, ResNet accepts 3-channel input. To make it work for 4-channel input, you have to add one extra layer (2D conv), pass the 4-channel input through this layer to make the output of this layer suitable for ResNet architecture.

steps

1. Copy the model weight

   ```
   weight = model.conv1.weight.clone()
   ```
2. Add the extra 2d conv for the 4-channel input

   ```
   model.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(4, 64, kernel_size=7, stride=2, padding=3, bias=False) #here 4 indicates 4-channel input
   ```
3. You can add Relu and BatchNorm on top of the extra con2d. In this example, I am not using.
4. Connect the extra cov2d with the ResNet model (the weight you copied before)

   ```
   with torch.no_grad():
       model.conv1.weight[:, :3] = weight
       model.conv1.weight[:, 3] = model.conv1.weight[:, 0]
   ```
5. Done

Sorry, I didn't modify your code. You can adjust the changes in your code.

Comment: Thanks, anw replacing ...conv1.weight by ...conv1.weight.data works for me. Because conv1.weight is nn.Parameter while conv1.weight.data is tensor, we just want to copy the tensor values only and avoid the Parameter wrapper with some gradient related stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `.data` of the first channels as well:

```py
res.conv1.weight[:,:3,:,:].data[...] = pretrained_weights
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved it, but I don't understand why.
Would anyone be able to give me an explanation of what nn.Parameter does? and why does it work?

```py
class Res50(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,  pretrained=True):
        super(Res50, self).__init__()

        self.de_pred = nn.Sequential(Conv2d(1024, 128, 1, same_padding=True, NL='relu'),
                                     Conv2d(128, 1, 1, same_padding=True, NL='relu'))
        
        initialize_weights(self.modules())
        res = models.resnet50(pretrained=pretrained)

        pretrained_weights = res.conv1.weight.clone()

        res.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(4, 64, kernel_size=7, stride=2, padding=3,bias=False)

        res.conv1.weight[:,:3,:,:] = torch.nn.Parameter(pretrained_weights)
        res.conv1.weight[:,3,:,:] = torch.nn.Parameter(pretrained_weights[:,1,:,:])
        
        self.frontend = nn.Sequential(
            res.conv1, res.bn1, res.relu, res.maxpool, res.layer1, res.layer2
        )
        
        self.own_reslayer_3 = make_res_layer(Bottleneck, 256, 6, stride=1)        
        self.own_reslayer_3.load_state_dict(res.layer3.state_dict())
```